# How to make my topology cycle run completely before starting it again?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a spout which does some processing in `nextTuple()` and emit values to Kafka bolt. Once the Kafka bolt acknowledges, spouts `ack()` method is called.

In my case before `ack()` method is finished, topology calls `nextTuple()` method of the spout.

Is there anyway to control over topology to start again only after the previous topology is finished completely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the config parameter "topology.max.spout.pending" to one. For this case, nextTuple() will not be called, before the previously emitted tuples got acked.

Comment: Yeah I found this out. Forgot to update here. I will mark this as Answer, this may help someone else. Thanks Matthias.